# apache karaf client getting Bundle installation rejected by hook when trying to feature:install

Tags: apache-karaf

I am trying to do this for the first time on my Test and Production Application Environments having Apache Karaf.

I had a production rollout yesterday and before proceeding I wanted to check the steps in Test environment.

Steps I performed:

```
service karaf-service stop 
repo-remove mvn:xxx.xxxxx.xxx/xxx/1.13-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
repo-remove mvn:xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy/1.13-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
```

---

```
repo-add mvn:xx.xxxx.xxx/xxx/1.14-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
repo-add mvn:xx.xxxx.xxx/yyy/1.14-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
```

repos successfully added/removed

next,
I run the commands:

---

```
karaf@root()> feature:install -v xxx 
Installing feature    xxx1.14-SNAPSHOT 
Installing feature activemq-camel 5.10.0 
Installing    feature cxf-core 3.0.1 
Installing feature camel-core 2.14.0    
Installing feature camel-jms 2.14.0 
Installing feature    camel-blueprint 2.14.0 
Installing feature camel-mail 2.14.0    
Installing feature camel-servlet 2.14.0 
Installing feature camel-cxf 2.14.0 
Installing feature camel-jaxb 2.14.0 
Installing feature camel-jackson 2.14.0 
Installing bundle    mvn:com.google.guava/guava/17.0 
Installing bundle    mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6 
Installing bundle    mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.4.1    
Installing bundle mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.2    
**Error executing command: Bundle installation rejected by hook.**
```

---

```
karaf@root()> feature:install -v yyy
Installing feature yyy 1.14-SNAPSHOT
Installing feature camel-core 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-blueprint 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-cxf 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-jaxb 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-jdbc 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-servlet 2.14.0
Installing feature camel-jackson 2.14.0
Installing bundle wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3
Installing bundle mvn:com.google.guava/guava/17.0
Installing bundle mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6
**Error executing command: Bundle installation rejected by hook.**
```

---

Tried doing everything.. checked all the logs.. but no clue what and where is wrong and how to resolve it?

Any helps on this would be highly appreciable

thanks

Comment: Look inside the karaf source code for that error "rejected by hook" to try to find out more. And if not in karaf then try its osgi libraries like apache felix.

Comment: This post is no more relevant hence closing. I didnt check or follow the proper steps.